# Does buildSuggestions of showSearch method run continuously?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new in flutter and I have a function to search working with API,and i have created a function called `_fetchData()` inside `StatefulWidget`:

```
_fetchData() async {
  print("fetchData Run");
  print(widget.query);
  this.setState((){
    isLoading=true;
  });
  final response = await http.get(URL+'search/keyword?api_key='+API_KEY+'&query='+widget.query);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(response.body);
    var list = json.decode(response.body)["results"] as List;
    keywordList = list.map<Keyword>((json)=>Keyword.fromJson(json)).toList();
    this.setState((){
      isLoading=false;
    });
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load photos');
  }
}
```

and i put my `StatefulWidget` in `buildSuggestions` like:

```
class SearchHome extends SearchDelegate {

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
  //widget
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
  //widget
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
  //widget
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    //SuggestKeyword is my statefullwidget with _fetchData() function inside
    return SuggestKeyword(query: query);
  }
}
```

but i'm confuse why `_fetchData()` keep running continuously, that's mean my apps keep hit an API, i think it's not good so i want to avoid it

I know i can put `SuggestKeyword` inside `buildResults`, but these method need user to submit/enter the keyboard to run, i want to search while the user is still typing, but `buildSuggestions` keep running even when user is not typing,

am i doing something wrong? any suggestion would appreciated!

Comment: `buildSuggestions` runs everytime a letter is entered. I dont really understand what you want

Comment: @JideGuruTheProgrammer _buildSuggestions runs everytime a **letter is entered**_. but the actual is wrong, `buildSuggestions` is run periodically thought, i want to call an API when user is typing, the example: when user type `av`, the program should call API with parameter `av` vice versa without submitting

Comment: If you want results to be shown after user enters a query like `av`, `buildResults` should be where u run the API call. `buildSuggestions` as the name implies is mean for `sugestions`, so it runs everytime you enter a letter(so as to make suggestions) and not periodically

Comment: @JideGuruTheProgrammer `buildResults` is calling when user has done input some text and pressing "Enter" (on the keyboard), but i want to show the result even if user still typing, so i'm used `buildSuggestions` instead of `buildResults`, but `buildSuggestions` still running even if user stop typing, i want to avoid it

Comment: When user stop typing, its continues the API Call right?

Comment: @JideGuruTheProgrammer yeah, my fetch function still running periodically,

Comment: What's the code for the `SuggestKeyword` widget?

Comment: @flix You need to share the code that calls `_fetchData`. Otherwise, we will not be able to tell you why it is being called more often than it should be.